# Map of coherent sheaves inducing isomorphism on the stalks at the generic point

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a finite morphism between Noetherian integral schemes that is surjective on the underlying topological spaces. Does there exist an integer $n>0$ and a coherent $O_X$-module $F$ such that there is a morphism of $O_Y$-modules $O_Y^n\rightarrow f_*F$ inducing an isomorphism on the stalks at the generic point of $Y$?

It is pretty easy to see that there must be a quasi-coherent $O_X$-module like this. Pick an affine open $V\subset Y$, then its inverse image [is](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01WI) an affine open $U\subset X$. It is easy to see that $O_U$ answers the question for the morphism $f|_{U}$. Therefore, if $i:U\rightarrow X$ denotes the inclusion, $i_* O_U$ is a quasi-coherent $O_X$-module ([because](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01LC) $i$ is [qcqs](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01OX)) answering the question (because the generic stalk can be computed on any non-empty open).

It appears, however, that this way we will rarely get a coherent sheaf. [EGA](http://www.numdam.org/article/PMIHES_1967__32__5_0.pdf#page=306) IV, partie quadrieme, Cor. 21.12.7 says that if $X$ is separated, the complement of $U$ has codimension 1 so $i_*$ has little chance to preserve coherence.

P.S. This is Hartshorne Ch. III Ex. 4.2 (a). I have consulted some solutions online and could not convince myself they really produce coherent (rather than quasi-coherent) sheaves. The same question has been asked on [Math Stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3197266/251240) but we have different perspective on the direction of the attack.

Comment: Idea how to approach this: take $f_* \mathcal{O}_X$, on a dense affine open $U\subseteq Y$ this is free, fix trivialization $f:\mathcal{O}_U^n \simeq (f_*\mathcal{O}_X)|_U$. If $Y\setminus U$ supported a Cartier divisor $D$, then there exists a line bundle $L= \mathcal{O}_Y(-mD)$ ($m\gg 0$)  on $Y$ such that $f$ extends to a morphism $g:L^{\oplus n}\to f_*\mathcal{O}_X$. Now tensor this by $L^{-1}$ and use the projection formula to get $g'\colon \mathcal{O}_Y^n \to (f_*\mathcal{O}_X)\otimes L^{-1} = f_* F$ where $F = f^* L^{-1}$. The problem is ensuring the existence of $L$.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger do you need something like ampleness of $L^\vee$ for your argument to work? I believe any coherent sheaf on an integral Noetherian scheme is a direct sum of a locally free sheaf and a torsion sheaf so without loss of generality assume that $f_* O_X$ is a vector bundle. If we want a morphism $L^{\otimes n}\rightarrow f_* O_X$ that induces an isomorphism at the generic point, we need $n=\mathrm{rank}f_*O_X$ independent maps $L\rightarrow f_*O_X$, which is the same as $n$ sections of $L^\vee\otimes f_*O_X$.

Comment: If $L^\vee \otimes f_* O_X$ were globally generated, we would have these sections (but you need ampleness of $L^\vee$ for this). I think on an arbitrary proper integral scheme over a field you won't find an ample line bundle. Or does your argument work for $O_X(D)$, $D$ an arbitrary effective Cartier divisor?

Comment: I think ampleness is really needed if you want the extension $g$ to be surjective. Here, the sections $f_i$ have poles of some order along the components of $D$, and if $m$ is bigger than those orders then you get an extension $g$, at least generically along the components of $D$. If $X$ is normal ($S_2$) along $D$ then this $g$ extends further to $X$.

Comment: Maybe the following could work: $L=K(X)$ is a finite extension of $K=K(Y)$, so $L = K l_1 + \cdots + K l_n$. Now take $\mathcal{F}$ be the $\mathcal{O}_X$--module $\mathcal{O}_X l_1 + \cdots + \mathcal{O}_X l_n$ which is an $\mathcal{O}_X$--submodule of the flasque $\mathcal{O}_X$--Module $\tilde{L}$.

Comment: @KarlSchwede maybe you could kindly clarify how to approach this Hartshorne exercise?

Comment: Here is how to go from quasi-coherent $F$ to coherent $F$: On any quasi-compact, quasi-separated scheme, quasi-coherent sheaves are filtered colimits of coherent sheaves. Since $\mathcal{O}_Y$ is compact for $Y$ such a scheme, the map $\mathcal{O}_Y^n\rightarrow f_*F$ factors through one of these coherent sheaves, which gives you what you want. The key facts here are the same as those appearing in Stacks Project 27.22 or EGA I.9.4.

Comment: @dhy is there some canonical way to construct such a colimit? Because, say, for smooth proper schemes over a field, there is some pretty specific geometry going on, so some colimits could be considered "less geometric" than the others.

Comment: @dhy also we need not some random coherent sheaf on $Y$, but a sheaf that is pushforwarded from $X$. To have such sheaf, we presumably should construct a sequence of coherent subsheaves of $i_*O_U$ on $X$ and then pushforward it to $Y$. But is it true that pushforward by a finite morphism, considered as a functor between categories of quasi-coherent sheaves, commutes with filtered colimits?

Comment: I'm sure that you can find more canonical-looking presentations in specific cases, but in general I don't know (other than some tautological presentations.) And yes, pushforward along a quasi-compact quasi-separated morphism commutes with filtered colimits (Proof: Reduce to case Y affine. In this case, pushforward is a finite limit, which commutes with filtered colimits.)

Comment: FWIW, the user appears to have been part of a group of accounts controlled by the same individual

Comment: Do anyone here know how to do the last part of this problem. I've gotten to the point where I have a map $f_*\mathcal{M}\to \mathcal{F}^r$ of coherent sheaves which is an isomorphism at the generic point and the former has vanishing higher cohomology groups. I want to conclude that $\mathcal{F}^r$ has vanishing cohomology groups but don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is basically a copy of dhy's comments with links (any mistakes are mine).

First, assume you know that for a finite surjective morphism $f:X\rightarrow Y$ between Noetherian integral affine schemes, there exists a positive integer $n$ and a morphism of $\mathcal{O}_Y$-modules $\mathcal{O}_Y^{\oplus n}\rightarrow f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ inducing an isomorphism at the generic point. This is shown in the linked question.

Now, we have a finite surjective morphism $f:X\rightarrow Y$ between Noetherian integral schemes. Pick a non-empty affine open $j:V\rightarrow Y$ whose inverse image is a non-empty affine open $i:U\rightarrow X$. The restriction $f|_U:U\rightarrow V$ is a finite surjective map ([by definition](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01WH)). We know therefore that there is a positive integer $n$ and a morphism of $\mathcal{O}_Y$-modules $j_*\mathcal{O}_V^{\oplus n}\rightarrow f_* i_* \mathcal{O}_U$ inducing an isomorphism at the generic point. This can be composed with the natural map $\mathcal{O}_Y\rightarrow j_*\mathcal{O}_V$ to get a morphism of $\mathcal{O}_Y$-modules $\mathcal{O}_Y^{\oplus n}\rightarrow f_* i_* \mathcal{O}_U$ inducing an isomorphism at the generic point.

On any qcqs scheme any quasi-coherent sheaf [is](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01PG) the directed colimit of its quasi-coherent subsheaves of finite type. Apply this to $i_*\mathcal{O}_U$. [Since](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01XZ) $X$ is locally Noetherian, these subsheaves are actually coherent.

We claim that the pushforward by a qcqs morphism, considered as a functor on the categories of quasi-coherent modules, commutes with directed colimits. First note that the functor of restriction to an open set commutes with colimits so the question is local on the target. Assume that the target is affine, then [express](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01LC) the pushforward as a kernel. The conclusion follows from the fact that kernels commute with directed colimits and the fact that the pushforward by a morphism between affine schemes commutes with directed colimits.

Therefore, we can pushforward the the directed colimit to get a colimit of coherent sheaves on $Y$ (they will be coherent because $f$ is proper) coconverging to $f_*i_*\mathcal{O}_U$.

Finally, use Lemma 34 and Proposition 75 [here](http://therisingsea.org/notes/ModulesOverAScheme.pdf) (the word "concentrated" means qcqs) to conclude that any coherent sheaf on a Noetherian scheme is a finitely presented object of the category of quasi-coherent sheaves (i.e. $\mathrm{Hom}(F, -)$ preserves directed colimits). Therefore, the map $\mathcal{O}_Y^{\oplus n}\rightarrow f_* i_*\mathcal{O}_U$ factors through a coherent $\mathcal{O}_Y$-module $G\subset f_* i_*\mathcal{O}_U$. To see that $\mathcal{O}_Y^{\oplus n}\rightarrow G$ induces an isomorphism at the generic point, first notice that it must induce an injection at the generic point (because its composition with the inclusion is an isomorphism) and second notice that the generic rank of $G$ does not exceed that of $f_* i_*\mathcal{O}_U$. An injective map between finite-dimensional vector spaces such that the dimension of the target does not exceed the dimension of the source must be an isomorphism. Game over.

Answer (score 2):

I think this can also be solved by taking the "coherent subsheaf generated by finitely many global sections of $i_* \mathcal{O}_U$". I'm not sure this is fundamentally different from Aknazar's solution, but it avoids the direct mention of (co)limits, and might be what Hartshorne had in mind.

As Aknazar, suppose we can solve the problem for affine schemes, and choose an open affine $j: V \hookrightarrow Y$ and let $i: U \hookrightarrow X$ be its preimage. Suppose we have a morphism
$$ \alpha_V:  \mathcal{O}_V^n \to (f|_U)_*\mathcal{O}_U$$
which is an isomorphism at the generic point $\eta$ of $Y$.

The problem is that $i_* \mathcal{O}$ is not in general coherent on $X$. But $\alpha_V$ chooses $n$ global sections $s_1,\dotsc,s_n \in \Gamma(X, i_* \mathcal{O}_U) = \Gamma(U, \mathcal{O}_U)$, which can be used to define a morphism $\alpha_X: \mathcal{O}_X^n \to i_* \mathcal{O}_U$. Let $\mathscr{G}$ be the image of this morphism. Then $\mathscr{G}$ is coherent, because for every open affine $\text{Spec }A = W \subset X$, $\mathscr{G}(W) \subset (i_*\mathcal{O}_U)(W)$ is the $A$-submodule generated by $s_1|_W,\dotsc,s_n|_W$.

This allows us to define the morphism
$$ \alpha_Y: \mathcal{O}_Y^n \to f_* \mathscr{G} \subset (f i)_* \mathcal{O}_U$$
by takting the same global sections $s_1,\dots,s_n \in \Gamma(Y, f_* \mathscr{G})$. At the generic point this yields
$$
\mathcal{O}^n_{Y, \eta} \xrightarrow{\alpha_{Y, \eta}} (f_*\mathscr{G})_\eta \hookrightarrow ((fi)_* \mathcal{O}_U)_\eta,
$$
and the composition is $\alpha_{U, \eta}$ which is an isomorphism. Hence $\alpha_{Y, \eta}$ is an isomorphism as well.